# How to make the picture not spin, but be in the same position when tracking the mouse movement

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make the picture not spin, but be in the same position when tracking the mouse movement. Or maybe I need to write the code in a different way? I've already tried many options, but since I'm just learning JS, I don't know in which direction to move. An example where the picture is not spinning [link](https://mac-template.webflow.io/) . I will be grateful for your help.

Here is my code:

```js
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("mousemove", eyeball);

function eyeball() {
  const eye = document.querySelectorAll(".eye");
  eye.forEach(function(eye) {
    let x = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().left) + (eye.clientWidth / 2);
    let y = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().top) + (eye.clientHeight / 2);

    let radian = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY - y);
    let rotation = (radian * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 270;
    eye.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)"
  });
}
```

```css
.contact {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  top: 35px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box .eye {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.box .eye::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url(https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/179/179531.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="eye"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. In the example website, you provided the eye moves in a square area and Its position is determined where the mouse is relative to the browser window and not the actual eye. Is something like that ok or do you want it to move like in your example code where it always faces the cursor and moves around a circular area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the web site you included the eye isn't really tracing a circle shape, it's bounded by a rectangle representing scaled screen dimensions.

```js
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("mousemove", eyeball);

function eyeball() {
  const pupils = document.querySelectorAll(".pupil");
  pupils.forEach((pupil) => {
    const mx = event.pageX
    const my = event.pageY
    // scale mouse position from screen space to percentages 15% - 85%
    const vx = scale(mx, 0, innerWidth, 15, 85)
    const vy = scale(my, 0, innerHeight, 15, 85)
    pupil.style.transform = `translate(${vx}%, ${vy}%)`
  });
}

// scales value from inMin - inMax range to outMin - outMax range
function scale(value, inMin, inMax, outMin, outMax) {
  const percent = (value - inMin) / (inMax - inMin);
  const out = percent * (outMax - outMin) + outMin;
  return out
}
```

```css
.contact {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  top: 35px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box .eye {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.box .eye .pupil {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/179/179531.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="eye">
      <div class="pupil"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```